# Can I use jQuery-UI Dialog with HTML5 full screen?

Tags: html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, html5-fullscreen

I've been working on a web application that, among other things, uses Google Maps API to display a map of an area with "pins" marking points of interest.  When the user clicks on a pin, the application uses jQuery-UI Dialog to display information about the clicked pin in a dialog.

Later on, I decided that it might be nice to have a button the user can click on to make the map fullscreen.  This was no problem for the map, but when the user clicks on a pin, he cannot see the dialog unless he exits fullscreen mode.

This is presumably because the `div` that holds the dialog is outside the fullscreen `div` that holds the map.  I tried moving the `div` that holds the dialog inside the `div` that holds the map, but that doesn't work either; apparently, jQuery-UI moves the `div` to the end of the document.

Is there a practical way to make jQuery-UI Dialog play nice with HTML5 fullscreen?  I have seen other threads about this on other sites, but I haven't found a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 0):

By default the plugin appends your dialog `<div>` to the end of the body, which has the side effect of removing it from wherever you had placed it.

Using the [`appendTo`](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-appendTo) option of `.dialog` you can override this behavior:

```
$( "#yourDialog" ).dialog({
    appendTo: "#parentElement"
});
```

Where `"#parentElement"` is your `<div>` that is being set fullscreen.

Comment: I've just tried this, and it isn't working.  I tried doing this with the dialog `div` both inside and outside the fullscreen element, and I still see using the debugging that the dialog is being appended to the end of the document.  What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Poking around a little more, I found something that did work for me: I followed the `.dialog('open')` statement with `jQuery('.ui-dialog').appendTo('#parentElement')`